# View Java content in chrome 46/47

Tags: google-chrome, browser, java

As of chrome 46 and higher, there is no native way to enable npapi in chrome (registry/chrome flags). I would like to view java content in chrome.

Is there a way to view java content in (current) chrome browser, without using  [IE rendering extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=de)?

Comment: If you want to continue to use Chrome.  You will have to either use a version of Chrome that does support NPAPI, or add the support back into Chromium yourself and build it from source, if you required to use the most recent version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is by design, and the official statement [from Oracle](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) is:

> Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)
>
> The Java plug-in for web browsers relies on the cross platform plugin
>   architecture NPAPI, which has been supported by all major web browsers
>   for over a decade. Google's Chrome version 45 (scheduled for release
>   in September 2015) drops support for NPAPI, impacting plugins for
>   Silverlight, Java, Facebook Video and other similar NPAPI based
>   plugins.
>
> Java applications are offered through web browsers as either a web
>   start application (which do not interact with the browser once they
>   are launched) or as a Java applet (which might interact with the
>   browser). This change does not affect Web Start applications, it only
>   impacts applets.
>
> If you have problems accessing Java applications using Chrome, Oracle
>   recommends using Internet Explorer (Windows) or Safari (Mac OS X)
>   instead.
>
> Developers and System administrators looking for alternative ways to
>   support users of Chrome should see this blog regarding Launching Web
>   Start applications.

Along with the official statement regarding [Chrome:](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033)

> Access websites that use NPAPI
>
> NPAPI plugins can't be enabled, so if
>   you want to use a website that uses an NPAPI plugin, you’ll need to
>   use a different web browser.

The developer will need to change how it works, or you will need to use a different browser or an older, less secure browser.